# Apache-POI : How to set background color of a cell when creating spreadsheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In Apache POI 4.0 I want to set an Excel cell background color like this :

```
IndexedColorMap colorMap = workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors();
style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.BLUE, colorMap).getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Title");
    header.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
```

.. but all I get are black cells. I've tried many things, but result is always the same.

How can I set the background color of an Excel cell in Apache POI 4.0 ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this for a hex or rgb value?

Comment: No, I stopped looking for it. I used @Vasif's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code for background style

style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());

Comment: Thanks that worked. What if I'd like to use a hex value, e.g. "#AEAEAE". Is there a way of providing custom values ?

Comment: Maybe you can try to create your rgb using `IndexedColorMap`, but I never used

style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new IndexedColorMap() {
.....